# Dynamically created colgroup not working

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, html-table

I wrote a jQuery plugin that, among other things, sets the width of a table columns using `colgroup`, and allows them to be resized by dragging the headers left or right. I posted a stripped down version of it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/YqCsY/). It works fine in Firefox (3.6 at least), but fails in other browsers, and I'm clueless about why.

I noticed that when I create a table with a colgroup directly in the markup, the widths are fine, but when I add them later using jQuery they are not. Maybe I'm not adding them where they're supposed to be, or maybe I'm unknowingly relying on deprecated or browser-specific behavior, I have no idea.

The resizing of the headers is done by changing the `width` attribute of each `col`, in response to a mouse drag. In principle it's working fine, it has no observable effects in the other browsers due to the colgroup issue (`console.log` shows the events are fired correctly).

Any help with this issue will be appreciated. Suggestions on how to accomplish the same thing without colgroups are also welcome! (remembering that a header resize should change the widths of all tds in the column)

Simplified code:

```
var colgroup = $('<colgroup/>');
table.find("td,th").each(function() {
    create_col($(this)).appendTo(colgroup);
});
colgroup.appendTo(table);

// Inside create_col:
var col = $('<col width="' + width + '"/>');
return col;
```

Full code: [jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/YqCsY/](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/YqCsY/)

P.S. Although unrelated to the problem, if anyone also knows a cross-browser way to make the headers **unselectable** please tell me, the resizing part will feel more "natural" this way. The relevant line in the (full) example is:

```
th.attr("unselectable","on").css("-moz-user-select","none")
```

---

**Update**: Apparently, Firefox accepts the `colgroup` being **below** `tbody`, but other browsers require it to be **above**...

```
// colgroup.appendTo(table);
colgroup.prependTo(table);
```

This fixed things in Chrome and Safari, <strike>but Opera is still not working</strike> and Opera.

Comment: In what browsers it doesn't work?

Comment: Chrome (17), Opera (11), Safari (4). I'm running all them in Windows XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the update, `colgroup` must preceed `tbody` in a table, for most browsers to consider it.

```
// colgroup.appendTo(table);
colgroup.prependTo(table);
```

**Edit:** for the unselectable problem, found an answer in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/826782/520779).